# Jni example header files not getting generated

Tags: android, java-native-interface, header-files

I am getting the following errors when I run the below command to create header files in my  JNI project

```
   root@bsd-pc1907:/home/sat/KISHORE/kishore workspace/Ivijni/bin/classes/com/ivi/jni# javah JniActivity
   error: cannot access JniActivity
   bad class file: RegularFileObject[./JniActivity.class]
   class file contains wrong class: com.ivi.jni.JniActivity
   Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
   com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort
   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.completionError(Check.java:180)
   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocEnv.loadClass(DocEnv.java:159)
   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.RootDocImpl.<init>(RootDocImpl.java:95)
   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool.getRootDocImpl(JavadocTool.java:188)
   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:364)
   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:162)
   at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:113)
   at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:153)
    javadoc: error - fatal error
  2 errors
```

My JniActivity.java

```
public class JniActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    System.loadLibrary("hellojni");
    new JniActivity().sayHello();

}
private native void sayHello();

}
```

hellojni.cpp

```
 #include "hellojni.h"
 #include  <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 void sayHello () {
 cout << "Hello World Again!" << endl;
 return;
 }
```

Any help is always appreciated,Thanks

Comment: plz see [Tutorial: Android JNI](http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/04/tutorial-android-jni/) excellent tutorial for creating JNI Header

Answer (score 0):

> root@bsd-pc1907:/home/sat/KISHORE/kishore workspace/Ivijni/bin/classes/com/ivi/jni# javah JniActivity

There are several problems here.

1. You are in the wrong directory. You should be in `/home/sat/KISHORE/kishore workspace/Ivijni/bin/classes`.
2. You are issuing the wrong command.
   The argument to `javah`, as to `javap`, `rmic`, and all the other Java utilities that deal with .class files, is a fully qualified class name, including the package name. You aren't supplying that so you are getting errors.